# Recommend shortcut in Siri after creating Siri shortcut - React Native

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, sirishortcuts

I have successfully implemented shortcut in React Native project via `react-native-siri-shortcut` npm.

I am able to see all those shortcuts in Shortcut app(in iOS).

When I open Siri and speak them, Siri just opens my app.

I have added **SiriShortcutListener** in my app, and just displayed alert.

I don't know how to make Siri recommend some stuff or perform the action as I want it to.

Do I have to make any UI for that? Also, how `activityType` should be used?

Any proper link or tutorial/help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the Siri shortcut will work on `react-native` but as a part of iOS native app development, you have to add `SiriKit Intent Definition File` to your project.

[image]

Once you add that file to your project you will have to add New Intent and have to configure it the way you would like to utilize it in your app.

[image]

I hope it will give some hint on your further research or developing.

Comment: Yes, I am researching on iOS tutorials as well. The only hurdle is I don't have any experience with iOS development.